# Vertex marker in Edit Vertices not appearing on half screen

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.5, debugging

I'm using ArcMap on ArcGIS Desktop 10.5 and when I enter the Edit Vertices context, the vertex markers on the left side of the screen are hidden. You can click on them, but the marker does not appear. In the screenshot you can see I've selected a line for editing, the right side of the screen shows the line and vertex markers but at a certain point as you move left you see they no long appear.

Has anyone else experienced this bug or have any suggestions on fixing it?

[image]

Comment: Have you tried restarting ArcGIS (and possibly also your computer)? Sometimes that fixes weird bugs that suddenly appear like this.

Comment: The issue is persistent, it did not just appear.